# How to format a list of int into a hex representation?

Tags: python, formatting, hex

This is more a question of style and what is pythonic. I like to create a string out of a list of ids. My current code looks like that:

```
idL = [1, 2, 64, 32, 3200, 441122]
txt = ""
for id in idL:
    if txt != "":
        txt += "-"
    txt += "{:04X}".format(id)
print(txt)
```

I guess that there is a more pythonic way to do the formating. Like a generator expression.

I was also thinking if something like

```
txt += f"{id.hex()}"
```

works better - but I somehow failed to get capital letters done.

Any ideas and suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```py
idL = [1, 2, 64, 32, 3200, 441122]
txt = "-".join("{:04X}".format(id) for id in idL)
print(txt)
```

Edit: arguably cleaner method (credit to @Swifty)

```py
txt = "-".join(f"{id:04X}" for id in idL)
```

Comment: I prefer `f"{id:04X}"` which I find more readable than using .format, but `.join` is indeed the way to go imo.